# CSOM : Page not loading as expected

Tags: 2013, csom

I have page with 5 webparts all executed using CSOM and JSOM code . All webparts maintain their own js and css files . I am facing issues with the CSOM code , the code it behaves unexpectedly sometimes the code doesnt trigger , it execute twice sometimes . I suspect the issue is with the way the page is loaded with the javascripts . Any suggestions on how to make the page load only once or best practises for CSOM ? Also to mention i get spcontext is undefined error sometimes .

Comment: Ask your question with codes in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Otherwise show your code over here

Comment: Sounds like a [MDS](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=mds) issue

Answer (score 1):

Without code there is only guessing. You write your web parts have all own js files, but this does not mean they have not a single global scope. Maybe this is a timing problem with some variables used in different js files.

Try to use [immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to get local scopes of your variables.